# Проблемы с минификацией HTML в AngularJS-проекте

Tags: html, css, angularjs, сборка, grunt

Есть вот такой HTML:

```
<div class="footer">
    <div class="tools">
        <a role="button" class="material-button" href="{{item.url}}" target="_blank">
            <i class="icon fa fa-file-text"></i> Запись
        </a>
        <button type="button" class="material-button" ng-click="copyPost(item)">
            <i class="icon fa fa-clipboard"></i> Копировать
        </button> 
        <share url="{{item.url}}" title="{{item.source.name}}" description="{{item.text}}"></share>
    </div>
</div>
```

HTML-шаблон компонента Share:

```
<div class="share-block">
    <a class="material-button share vk" target="_blank" href="{{vk}}"><i class="fa fa-vk"></i></a>
    <a class="material-button share fb" target="_blank" href="{{fb}}"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
    <a class="material-button share ok" target="_blank" href="{{ok}}"><i class="fa fa-odnoklassniki"></i></a>
    <a class="material-button share gp" target="_blank" href="{{gp}}"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
</div>
```

В браузере он выводится вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После минификации HTML, он выглядит вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На сколько я понял, это из за того, что при минификации были убраны пробелы. Я залез в сгенерированный минифицированный HTML, чтобы разобраться. В общем, к моему удивлению, между тегами <a> в компоненте share ЕСТЬ пробелы. Между тегом <a> и <button>, которые находятся в диве `tools` - НЕТ пробела.

Поясните мне, где здесь логика, как исправить ситуацию? Ведь по идее, там должен быть пробел, раз он есть в компоненте share между тегами <a>.

Grunt, grunt-angular-templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, единственным более-менее нормальным решением я нашел следующее. Задаем для всей страницы `font-size: 0`:

```
body {
  font-size: 0;
}
```

Далее, везде, где используем текст задаем нужный размер шрифта:

```
.text {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

В таком случае, мы решаем проблему с пробелами в HTML-разметке и CSS. Страницы выглядят одинаково и до, и после сборки.

Answer (score 0):

Сбросьте дефолтный margin у inline-block элементов, задайте например в CSS margin-right: 4px

```
.material-button {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 4px;
}
```

Upd. Для уверенности можно ещё сбросить margin с помощью комментария

```
<a class="material-button"></a><!--
--><a class="material-button"></a>
```

Comment: В таком случае до и после минификации страницы будут выглядеть по разному.